# How with JavaScript to load content from other website into iframe on localhost by keeping dom-structure to get to it with getElementsByTagName

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

How with JavaScript to load content from other website into iframe on localhost by keeping dom-structure to get to it with getElementsByTagName?

When loaded content in iframe is not to see by getElementsByTagName("*"), how to get to dom-elements of this content?

Comment: same origin policy will not allow it.

Comment: Unless you control the server of the "other website", what you are trying to do is impossible within a browser using JavaScript due to the security built into web browsers.

Comment: Can you use server side code ?

Answer (score -1):

```
            $.ajax('URLtoLoad', {
                method:'GET'
            }).complete(function(res) {
                if(res.responseText) {
                    document.getElementById('myIframe').innerHTML = res.responseText;
                }
            });
```

using jquery and ajax to load content into the `<div id="myIframe"></div>`

Comment: how rightly to load jquery into html by cdn? What is the correct line?

Comment: Is than jquery server-side content loading tool?

Comment: How to disable this security?